# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem “spree_core"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, spree

I’m trying to install spree_braintree gem to integrate braintree gateway with spree 3.0.1. When I run “bundle install”, I get this error “Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem “spree_core”". This is my Gemfile.

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

    # Use Unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

    group :development, :test do
      # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
      gem 'byebug'

      # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using  in views
      gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

      # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
      gem 'spring'
    end


    gem 'spree', '3.0.1'
    gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
    gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
    gem 'spree_braintree', :git => 'git://github.com/rortechie/spree-braintree.git

'
```

```
Error message:
<pre>
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_braintree (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (~> 1.0.0) ruby

    spree (= 3.0.1) ruby depends on
      spree_sample (= 3.0.1) ruby depends on
        spree_core (3.0.1)
```

I also tried to remove Gemfile.lock and run bundle install but it didn't help.I am using ruby 2.2.2 and rails 4.2.1.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory.  You will either need to remove the version number from `spree` and let the bundler send you back the dark ages at/around version `1.0.0` or drop the requirement for `spree_braintree`.  Why are you specifying `github` repositories for each of these and not just letting the bundler get the latest/stable version?

Comment: I experimented a bit and it seems like those last three gems are going to be a challenge.  I took off the version number for `spree` and removed the git repository links for the next two, but even the latest versions of these two are so old that they are pulling in incompatible stuff (at least with some of your other gems).  I couldn't remove the git requirement for the very last gem, which means it doesn't exist in the "Ruby Gems" system.  If you really need these three, you may need to roll back to Rails 3.1 or something.

Comment: what a mess. seems that spree_braintree hasn't been updated in more than 3 years. if you really need to use this, what I would so is fork the github repo, update the gem spec to something that is recent and give it a shot

Comment: The latest "instructions" from Spree, supposed to work with Rails 4.2, create this problem - even if you touch/add nothing.  Even the few lines they give in the "how to" do not even work, so you have to improvise.  If you upgrade Rails, then StateMachine fails, because those guys made changes that break working code (typical, in this community).  Add their "fix" line, and that crashes your app.  Huge mess - hope there is an alternative to Spree.